# Reading and writing files in c

Tags: c

i wanna know why my program can't input the numbers of my .txt file them into my array. It reads them but i can't manage to input them into an array for later use.
Can anybody help me to understand better the management of reading and writing files in c, please i'm new at this topic, i know i'm supposed to use int instead of chars since my .txt file contains only numbers. But with the functions such as fgets is for chars only i think.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        FILE* file;
        char name[10] = "100.txt";
        char line[10];
        int n;
        char i[5];
        file = fopen(name, "rt");

        if (file == NULL)
        {
            printf("There is no such file!\n");
            return 0;
        }
        for (n=0; n < 100; n++){
        fgets(line, 5, file);
        //puts(line);
        i[n]=line;
        puts(i[n]);
        }
        fclose(file);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: use `fscanf` instead of fgets

Comment: if i add fscanf and error pops up, it says: error: cannot convert 'char*' to 'FILE* {aka_iobuf*}'for argument '1' to 'int fscanf(FILE*, const char*, ...)' //for line 18;
error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive] //for line 20;
error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive] //for line 21;

Comment: You've only allocated 5 elements for the `i` array, but you're indexing possibly up to 100 in your `for` loop! And it's the wrong type. The type of `i[n]` is a `char` and you're assigning a character pointer to it (`line`). That's going to be big trouble. Aren't you getting compiler warnings?

Comment: 6
56
15
51
32
89
61
81
73
12
35
90
97
19
33
46
65
9
22
42
48
50
53
87
38
66
37
10
79
43
67
54
96
52
13
27
29
85
80
41
39
92
98
93
1
63
69
95
4
36
8
59
99
25
2
72
100
74
88
84
70
82
17
30
44
57
7
91
75
28
71
18
58
78
40
68
3
24
60
83
49
55
11
20
16
26
23
62
77
64
86
34
45
76
14
47
5
21
94
31  this is the content of 100.txt they're just 100 random numbers from 1 to 100

Comment: `i[n]=line;` doesn't make any sense. What do you think this does?

Comment: I don't understand why you declare line to be 10 positions and then do a `fscanf()` to fill only 5.  Why don't use `sizeof line` instead? Also, what you have in line is the characters that form your number in the character set of your machine, don't confuse that with a number, they must be somewhat converted (use ***sscanf(3)*** or ***atoi(3)*** functions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you switch to fscanf you can use int instead of char, and given that you are parsing a text file containing numbers it makes more sense. Assuming your 100.txt has 100 number separated by a whitespace this should work:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE* file;
    char name[10] = "100.txt";
    char line[10];
    int n;
    int numberArray[100];
    file = fopen(name, "rt");

    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("There is no such file!\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (n=0; n < 100; n++){
        fscanf(file, "%d", &numberArray[n]);
    }
    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the link for an explanation of [fscanf](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm).

EDIT:

There is another, and more elegant solution, to use fscanf:

```
while (fscanf(file,"%d",&numberArray[n++]) == 1);
```

in that way you loop through your text file as long as there are numbers (i.e. until EOF). Be careful as the program *could crash* if the count of numbers in the text file is greater than the space allocated for the array.

For writing back to a file:

```
FILE* fp = fopen( "out_file.txt", "w" ); // Open file for writing
int arrNumSize = sizeof(numberArray) / sizeof(int);
for (int i = 0; i < arrNumSize; i++)
{ 
    fprintf(fp, "%d", numberArray[i] );
}

fclose(fp);
```

Comment: thank you man, you really helped me, now that i have my array i'm gonna sort it with the insertion sort algorithm, but i have one more quesrtion, once i sort it, i want my new sorted array, written into a new file, how do i do that?

Comment: same process but using fprintf. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fprintf.htm please mark the question as answered if it worked for you.

Comment: `fprintf(fp, "%d", numberArray[i] );` : I think that there is a need to separate :-D

Comment: @JoseManuelAlarcon I think counting sort is better than insertion sort.

Comment: *in that way you loop through your text file as long as there are numbers* -- or until your program crashes as there is only space for 100 numbers in the Array.